# CompositeView where children can come from multiple collections

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, typescript, marionette

Here is what I need in a nutshell.

I need to show a dropdown/combobox where the children can come from many collections. All these collections' models have a text attribute which I will show in the dropdown.

I am wondering if it is possible to create the dropdown's list from many collections.

Namely:

```
Collection one has:
Text: A, Fungus: 9
Text: B, Fungus: 7
Text: C, Fungus: 6

Collection 2 has:
Text: Q, NumberOfBugs: 8
Text: R, NumberOfBugs: 9
Text: S, NumberOfBugs: 7
```

The list for my dropdown ends up looking like:

```
<option>A</option>
<option>A</option>
<option>A</option>
<option>Q</option>
<option>R</option>
<option>S</option>
```

So that if I select A, I want to be able to get A's model with the Fungus attribute, and if I select R I want R's model which has the NumberOfBugs attribute.

The idea is they are 2 collections with common attributes, but in the backend correspond to different models.

Is there some way to do this in Marionette/Backbone?

Some way to create a dropdown that has multiple data sources / collections?

Merging into one collection will not work because sync / fetch operations will not work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if those collection always work together in your application, you could make them a single collection from start and then use subcollections using something like [backbone-filtered-collection](https://github.com/jmorrell/backbone-filtered-collection) for custom behaviors and sync / fetch: models added to a subcollection would be also added to the general one.

```
var general = new Backbone.Collection
var fungus = new FilteredCollection(general)
var bugs = new FilteredCollection(general)

fungus.filterBy(function(model){
  return model.has('fungus')
})

bugs.filterBy(function(model){
  return model.has('numberOfBugs')
})

general.add([
    {text: 'A', fungus: 9},
    {text: 'B', fungus: 7},
    {text: 'C', fungus: 6},
    {text: 'Q', numberOfBugs: 8},
    {text: 'R', numberOfBugs: 9},
    {text: 'S', numberOfBugs: 7}
  ])



// general.length => 6
// fungus.length => 3
// bugs.length => 3
```

hope it helps

Comment: The add method of a FilteredCollection is blacklisted?

Comment: @Milo - what do you mean by "blacklisted"?

Comment: @Milo sorry, my code was incomplete without the `filterBy` functions, that should make more sense now. Notice that `fungus.add` and `bugs.add` are just proxies of `general.add`, and can thus be used indifferently